# Defined but have not been rendered for the layout page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get this error:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts".
```

With the following code:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model BabyStoreII.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Modern Business - @ViewBag.Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/modern-business.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Shop by Category", "Index", "Categories")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("View all our Products", "Index", "Products")</li>
                </ul>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBox("Search", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search Products" })
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                }
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/js/modern-business.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my client side validation does not work. It only works when I send the form to server but when I just lose focus an input box, the validation does not kick in. Below is my Model Validation:

**Category.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BabyStoreII.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Category name cannot be blank.")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a category name between 3 and 50 characters in length.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a category beginning with a capital letter and made up of letters and spaces only.")]
        [Display(Name="Category Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is in my shared folder. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `layout` page you missing `render script section`.
So try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Modern Business - @ViewBag.Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("/css/modern-business.css")" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Shop by Category", "Index", "Categories")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("View all our Products", "Index", "Products")</li>
                </ul>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left" }))
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBox("Search", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search Products" })
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                }
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/js/bootstrap.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("/js/modern-business.js")"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

And If you are not using `_ViewStart.cshtml` then use

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";   
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

In your `create.cshtml` page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Layout on your page, Please change your **Create.cshtml** code :

```html
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";    
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your create.cshtml with below code

```
    @model BabyStoreII.Models.Category

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Category</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```